# 2 Way IR communication for my robot

Tags: wireless, infrared

My next robotics project is a "1 cubic inch robot" and I am planning to add a 2 way wireless communication between my robot and a computer. Since for that size Power is a big bottleneck the best I could come up is a IR transceiver. So how can I achieve this ?

If I use a 38khz receiver then I might end up receiving the same transmit signal ? what Is the best option I can use in my application ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nordic nRF24L01 RF chips have a 33mW power consumption in Rx mode and much less in Tx. Not really answering your IR question, but I thought I'd mention them because you can buy ready made USB dongles which would speed up your development. It does also mean that line of sight isn't an issue!

Answer (score 2):

I would disable receiver while transmitting and would implement guaranteed packet delivery - when you are not receiving confirmation with correct crc packet is resent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a baffle - It's just a piece of something opaque between your receiver and transmitter that should prevent it from be inadvertently picked up.